# Java session attribute missing/lost

Tags: java, session, jsf-2

Working with JSF2 and Richfaces 4.0. I have been unsuccessfully trying to debug a lost session attribute for days now.
I have a page flow that takes the user from page1 to page2 and then back to page1. A session attribute is added when user clicks a button to navigate to page2. This attribute is used  in page2 and in page1 when the user returns to it.
When debugging, I can see the session attribute all the way to page2, but when user clicks on a button in page2 to return to page1 the attribute disappears.

I have no idea why this is happening. I am 100% sure I am adding the attribute to the session and not the request. I have been analyzing the code for days now.

I have other pages where attributes are added to the session and they work fine.

Any debugging suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Is there anything else in your request flow that modifies the session? Is there an HTTP/HTTPS change? Are you running in a clustered environment? Other than that... not much can go wrong with session attributes.

Comment: No, the page2 loads a report in a UIExtendeddatatable. A continue button at the end of the report takes the user to page1 where the attribute disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake. Missed a filter that removed the attribute. Thanks.

Comment: Heh; yeah, figured it'd be something like that... Spooky action at a distance makes debugging a pain sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the browser is sending the same session ID cookie on every request.

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for this.

Comment: I checked the getId() method of the session on all method calls and its same Id.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was switching between secured and not secured pages during the processing and that was causing loosing the session.
I made sure it was https (secured) all the way and that fixed the problem.